# How to put icon in placeholder in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to put icon in placeholder. I tried this code:

```
<md-input name="name">
   <md-placeholder>
      <i class="material-icons app-input-icon">face</i> Name
   </md-placeholder>
</md-input>
```

It was working (was showing icon with placeholder) before I reinstalled angular material and updated the angular cli.
For this code browser is giving this error now: "'md-input' is not a known element".

then I tried this code:

```
 <md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Name" name="name2">
 </md-input-container>
```

It is working properly but How can I put 'face' icon in its placeholder ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem was not the md-placeholder tag. Just like the error said, it was md-input which was deprecated. Angular Material recently changed his md-input tag into a mdInput directive.

But the md-placeholder is still working (not sure if it will last though).

The following code should work then :

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-placeholder>
        <md-icon>face</md-icon> Name
    </md-placeholder>
    <input mdInput name="name">
</md-input-container>
```

An alternative is to use the mdPrefix or mdSuffix directives to your md-icon tag. That will display your icon on the left or right of your input, but it won't follow the placeholder when you click on it.

Example :

```
<md-input-container>
    <md-icon mdPrefix>face</md-icon>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Name" name="name">
</md-input-container>
```

[Check the API reference for more informations.](https://material.angular.io/components/component/input)

Comment: Hey Remy. Do you get any error message ?

I just made a plunkr with the last version on Angular Material 2 (v.2.0.0-beta.6) and it works just fine.

You can check it here : http://plnkr.co/edit/XsmXJVgv5C91WniQfPAn?p=preview

Comment: I used Angular 1.6.4 ^^. The solution was to add class="md-icon-float md-icon-right" to the <md-input-container>

Comment: The mdPrefix, now matPrefix example works for me with a mat-select. The other broke the page. FWIW.

Comment: For Angular 5+ Material 2 using suffix (no placeholder):  ```<mat-form-field>
    <mat-icon mdSuffix>mode_edit</mat-icon>
    <input matInput placeholder="Name">
  </mat-form-field>```

Comment: And similar for prefix icon: ```<mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Amount</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="0.0">
        <mat-icon matPrefix>attach_money</mat-icon>
      </mat-form-field>```

Comment: Finally, a fancy placeholder icon with material 2 using the latest way: ```<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option>- None -</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="option">Bla2</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-placeholder><mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon> <b> Fancy</b> <i> placeholder</i></mat-placeholder>
  </mat-form-field>```

Answer (score 8):

### Angular 6

```
.example-full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
<mat-form-field  class="example-full-width">
 <mat-icon matPrefix>email</mat-icon>
  <input matInput
   type="email"
   tabindex="1"
   placeholder="Your Email"
   formControlName="email">
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 2):

mat-suffix didn't work for me either. Keeping up with their docs is always a chore, but as of 5.1.1 this should work:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-form-field">
  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Clearable input" [(ngModel)]="value"/>
  <button mat-button *ngIf="value" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="value=''">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Source:** "Input with a clear button" example here: https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <mat-toolbar class="table-search">
        <span class="fileter-width"><mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput [(ngModel)] = "value"  placeholder="Search">
                    <button mat-button class="remove-search" matSuffix  mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click) = "value=''">
                        <i class="fa fa-remove"> </i>
                    </button>
                </mat-form-field></span>
    </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```